Seleccionar idioma en Codeigniter 4
Según el manual, para seleccionar el lenguaje en Codeigniter 4 hay que indicar en la ruta el valor de la variable locale de esta manera:
$routes->get('{locale}/productos/new', 'Productos::new', ['filter' => 'checkUserPermissions']);

Así, indicando las siglas del idioma en la URL, el framework seleccionará el idioma indicado. Por ejemplo:
localhost/empresa/public/es/productos/new

Pero, ¿Qué pasa si la ruta ya estaba definida en un link como éste de abajo?
<a href="<?= base_url('productos/new') ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="bi bi-plus-lg"></i> <?= lang('App.productos.bNuevo') ?></a>

En este caso, la ruta del link ya no esta definida y el framework no la encuentra.
He intentado incluir la variable locale en $baseURL, pero la toma como un string y no como variable.
¿Cómo puedo resolver este problema?
Gracias de antemano.

Hola. Explica de qué modo has definido tus locales soportados y qué configuración tienes, tal y como explica la documentación: Si el valor no coincide con una configuración regional válida como se define en $supportedLocales en app/Config/App.php, se usará la configuración regional predeterminada ...

Solucionado. Hay que incluir $locale en el link:
<a href="<?= base_url($locale.'/productos/new') ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="bi bi-plus-lg"></i> <?= lang('App.productos.bNuevo') ?></a>

